# Cannot get the area of a triangle to display

Tags: c, codeblocks

We have to get the user to input 6 points and then calculate the area of the triangle formed between them.

This is my code for that:

```
//Purpose of the program is to have the user input 6 points, have a triangle made from those points and then calculate the area of said triangle

int main()
{
   //declaring variables. point1x is the x value for point 1 etc etc
    float point1x;
    float point1y;
    float point2x;
    float point2y;
    float point3x;
    float point3y;
    float side1;
    float side2;
    float side3;
    float svariable;
    float triangleArea;
//getting user to enter in the points
    printf ("Please enter point 1x: ");
    scanf ("%point1x", &point1x);


    printf ("Please enter point 1y: ");
    scanf ("%point1y", &point1y);


    printf ("Please enter point 2x: ");
    scanf ("%point2x", &point2x);


    printf ("Please enter point 2y: ");
    scanf ("%point2y", &point2y);


    printf ("Please enter point 3x: ");
    scanf ("%point3x", &point3x);


    printf ("Please enter point 3y: ");
    scanf ("%point3y", &point3y);

//calculating the lengths of the triangle

    side1=sqrt(((point1x-point2x)*(point1x-point2x))+((point1y-point2y)*(point1y-point2y)));

    side2=sqrt(((point1x-point3x)*(point1x-point3x))+((point1y-point3y)*(point1y-point3y)));

    side3=sqrt(((point2x-point3x)*(point2x-point3x))+((point2y-point3y)*(point2y-point3y)));

//svalue is needed for Heron's formula

    svariable=(((side1)*(side2)*(side3))/2);

//implementing herons formula

    triangleArea=(sqrt(svariable*(((svariable-side1)*(svariable-side2)*(svariable-side3)))));


    printf("the triangle area is: %f", triangleArea);

}
```

I dont know what is going wrong and why it is not working. I can't see a problem in the math either. I am using Heron's formula.

Comment: Your `scanf` statement is incorrect, it should be `scanf("%f",&variable_name);`.

Answer (score 1):

On the math side, you misunderstood Heron's formula:

```
svariable=(((side1)*(side2)*(side3))/2);
```

Should really be

```
svariable= (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be other issues, but the most obvious one is that you are using `scanf` incorrectly. Here is correct usage, and here is some [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

```
  printf ("Please enter point 1x: ");
  scanf ("%f", &point1x);
```

Comment: Ok merlin thank you. Now an actual number is being displayed. However when I use the points (-2,2),(2,2) and (0,-2) I get an area over a 1000. This must mean there's a math error but I dont know where it is.

Comment: @user113528, The best way to debug math errors is to print out all intermediate values and make sure they are equal to what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to include `stdio.h` and `math.h`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
```

In your `scanf` calls, you're going to want to do change the string to a format string expecting a floating point number.

Example: `scanf("%f", &point1x);`

And do this for all your `scanf` calls.

Answer (score 0):

I would compute the area using the cross product feature :

```
V1 X V2 = area contained by those two vectors
```

Thus to have the area of the triangle between 3 points, it is sufficient to use any two vectors (sides) as follows :

```
v1 = p1p2
v2 = p1p3

v1_x = (x2 - x1)
v1_y = (y2 - y1)
v2_x = (x3 - x1)
v2_y = (y3 - y1)

CROSS = v1_X * v2_y - v1_y * v2_x
```

and

```
area = CROSS /2
```

Comment: Interesting, however I don't believe OP was really asking for a different algorithm.

Comment: @chrk: It's not specified (different algorithm) even after correcting `scanf` he might be having wrong area according to Peter's answer, so I guess it's not wrong to propose another approach